# node.js - express - send data - form

Tags: forms, node.js, express

I use node.js - Express. I have a page (index.html) and html div (id = box) and input (id = inputUser). I want to express through insert (when the page loads) text into the div and input.

Thanks for the advice!

Client:

```
<form method="post" action="/">
    <input type="text" name="inputUser" id="inputUser" />
    <div id="box"></div>
</form>
```

Server:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index.html', { layout: false });
});

app.post('/', function(req, res){
});
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Do you want to render some dynamic variables at runtime?

Comment: Yes, I want the page is loaded from the database to load data to div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I see in your code snippet above, you are probably using [EJS](https://github.com/visionmedia/ejs) as the view engine. You can pass the variables to the view just like you pass the false option for layout.

**Server**

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  functionToLoadDataFromDatabase(function(divData, userData) {
    // this is the callback
    res.render('index.html', { 
      layout: false,
      divData: divData,
      userData: userData
    });
  });
});
```

**Client-side**

```
<form method="post" action="/">
  <input type="text" name="inputUser" id="inputUser" value="<%= userData %>" />
  <div id="box"><%- divData %></div>
</form>
```

From the EJS documentation:

```
Escapes html by default with <%= code %>   
Unescaped buffering with <%- code %>
```

Comment: If you don't want to use ejs, then Ajax is your only option.